# How do i dynamically move className down to next sibling Element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I having issues moving the className "slide" down to the next sibling element everytime I click "stuff". It keeps staying at the second element in the list. The goal is to keep moving to the next slide? Any solutions on how I can solve this

In function Stuff() I'm able to set a class to the first slide then move it to the next, but it stops there. The goal is to keep moving the slide down on  click.

```
const searchGif = () => { 

  if(search.length > 0 ) {
    setLoading(true)
    fetch(url + search)
    .then((res) => {
      setLoading(false)
      return res.json()
    })
    .then((result) => { 
      setGiph(result.data.map(giph => {
      let randomImage = []
      randomImage.push( giph.images.fixed_height.url)
      const img =  randomImage[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImage.length)]
      console.log(giph.id)
      return img
      }))
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
      setLoading(false)
      console.log("Something Went Wrong ", error)
    })
  }
}

// moveElement = () => { 
//   var list = document.getElementsByClassName(".list_Items")
//   if(list.previousElementSibling) { 
    
//   }
// }


//Move class to next slide 
const moveToSlide =  (currentSlide, nextSlide, track) => { 

  currentSlide.classList.remove("slide")
  nextSlide.classList.add("slide")

}

//Track the current Slide 
function stuff () { 
 var v = document.querySelector(".all_Images")
 v.firstChild.classList.add("slide")

 const currentSlide = document.querySelector(".slide")
 const nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling

 moveToSlide(currentSlide,nextSlide)
 console.log(currentSlide.className, nextSlide.className)


}



  return (
    <>
    <div className = "center_Page">
    <div className ="title_search">
     <div className = "title">Anime Search Website</div>
     <input className='search'
     placeholder='search'
     onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
     value = {search}
     type = "text"


     >
       
     </input>
       
     <button
      onClick = {searchGif}
      
      >
        Another Gif? Maybe gm
      </button>
      <div className = "next_Gif">
     <ul className = "all_Images">
        {
          giph.map((gif) => { 
            return (
              <li key ={gif.id} id ="list_Items" className='current_Slide'> <img src = {gif}></img></li>
            )
          })
        }
        </ul>
        <button className= "nextButton"
        onClick={stuff}
        >
          Next Gift? NGMI
        </button>
    
        </div>
     
    

    </div>
    <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You're going at it the wrong way. With React it's all about *how* you render your elements. When looping over your slides  in `giph.map()` you'll need to render the `className` property of each slide based on an evaluation. The evaluation in your case being: is this the current slide? A way of keeping track of the current slide is by storing the index of the one that is currently active.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier ahhh I see and how might I do that? The goal is remove the uppermost gif on click to display the next gif in line.

Comment: Start of by creating a state with `useState` where you track the current slide index. For example: `const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);` When clicking, update the state with a new index, for example `1`. You can select which gif you render by selecting the gif from your list based on the state, for example `gifs[slideIndex]`. Though there are many examples and tutorials on how to do this. So for more details, I'd suggest that you do some research. Also look for some React basics, as the core concepts are important to get right.